# can I use 'get' to say that a date hasn't passed yet?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Can I use **'get'** to say that a date hasn't passed?

for example:

> Q: "Is it Christmas yet?"

> A: "No, we've not gotten there yet"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in American English.

In British English that would be *We've not got there yet*.

To expand my answer, the idiom is *get to*, and it can be used in any tense:

> *When we get to March, maybe we can start visiting each other's houses again*.

In affirmative sentences, it often implies a struggle to reach the point. So *We got to Christmas* doesn't just mean that Christmas has happened, but that we had a hard time before Christmas, and possibly after as well. But it doesn't have that implication in the negative, so your example is fine.

It is *got[ten] there* without "to", because with *here*, *there*, and *where*, with verbs of motion (which *get* counts as for this purpose, even though it's a metaphorical motion), we can omit the *to*:

> *Shall I go there?*

> *He came here*.

and so

> *I got there in time.*

all without *to*.